# AnkhSVN is not showing as a source control plugin in VS 2008 on windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ankhsvn

I installed AnkhSVN without error and when I open Visual Studio I don't see AnkhSVN as an available Source Control Plugin. The list is empty.

I've tried the usual - restart VS, reboot, repair installation but it won't seem to

Is it anything to do with me having 64-bit windows 7?

The registry location that I believe Ankh should be adding itself to is:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\SourceControlProviders\

and not

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\SourceControlProviders\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least thousands of users using AnkhSVN under Windows 7 64 bit without any problems. (And I'm one of them).

If you are just using an official MSI to install AnkhSVN (2.0, 2.1 or 2.2) you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely had an official MSI but it looks like I downloaded an older version (1.0.6). Just downloaded 2.1 and it's now working.

Comment: @Chris: 1.0.6 also works fine on a 64bit OS, but it only works for Visual Studio .NET and Visual Studio .NET 2003

Comment: I am also facing this problem. Have download and installed latest AnkhSVN just now. But can't see this in source control plugin list.. pls help